# « L'antique honneur du peuple à longue robe » ?

Tags: sens, poésie

Dans le trente-deuxième sonnet des [*Antiquités de Rome*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-101437&M=notice), [Bellay](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim_Du_Bellay) écrit ces vers célèbres :

> *Vanter te peuls, quelque bas que tu sois,*
>  *D'avoir chanté, le
>   premier des François,*
>  *L'antique honneur du peuple à longue
>   robe.*

Mais au juste, qui est le *peuple à longue robe* ? Les Français ? Et pourquoi l'appeler ainsi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les dignitaires grecs s'habillaient en *[tunique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sculpture_grecque_antique)* et les romains de *[toges](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toge)*, qui sont des robes magistrales ; elles n'étaient pas noires comme celles des juges actuels mais généralement blanches ou rouges.

Du Bellay fait ici allusion aux grecs quand il cite Apollon, mais cela pourrait concerner aussi les romains, depuis l'histoire de la fondation de Rome par Rémus et Romulus jusqu'à l'expansion de César.